# Is it better to process auto-complete/suggestions on the client or server?

Tags: sql-server, json, autocomplete, wildcard

I am building a web app that will use an auto-complete/suggestions for the end user as they type their information in. This will be specifically for entering Country, Province, City information.

*Do a wild card search on the database on each keystroke:*

```
SELECT CityName 
FROM City
WHERE CityName LIKE '%@CityName%'
```

*Return a list of all Cities to a given Province to the client and have the client do the matching:*

```
SELECT CityName 
FROM City
WHERE ProvinceID = @ProvinceID
```

These would be returned to the client as a JSON string via an ajax call to a web service. My thoughts are that javascript would be able to handle the list of 100+ entries via JSON faster than the database would be able to do a wildcard search, but I'd like the communities input.

Comment: I would really not send a new query to the database on every key stroke. Wow, that could be bad.

Comment: Don't fulfil this need with a relational database.  Googles autocomplete, for example, uses a BigData/NoSQL model to scale massively and be optimised for such searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I have used both techniques. If you are talking about 100 or so entries, and assuming each entry is very small, it will likely be faster to do the autocomplete filter on the client side. That will provide you with better response time (although probably negligible) and will reduce the load on your server.

Google actually does a live search while the user is typing, and it seems to be pretty responsive from the user's point of view. This is an example where the query must be executed server-side because the dataset is far too large to transfer to the client.

One thing you might do is wait until the user types two keystrokes before fetching the list from the server, thus narrowing down the results initially.  Of course, that adds complexity - you would then need to refresh the list if the user changes either of the first two keystrokes.

Comment: Google does Not do this with SQL.  There is a world of difference between doing this in a BigData/NoSQL manner and a Relational/SQL manner.

Comment: @Dems - Good point, I was not referring to Google's use of SQL per se, rather the reasons why you might want to have the server dynamically re-query the underlying dataset in response to user input rather than the client doing the same job.

Answer (score 2):

We have implemented same functionality using ajax auto complete control we wait the user type three keystroke before fetching the list from server we have not done any coding at client side we just assigned web services method which return list to ajax control and its start working

Answer (score 1):

In the end user's interest, it is always better to handle this client-side.

The Telerik Autocomplete controller allows for both ways.

Of course under load client-side autocomplete is likely to make the application crawl.